# One line Array iterator javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iterator, idioms

I am coming from Python and I am looking for a **single line iterator function** for any array, where I can ***also check a condition and return*** a simple change to the items.

Expected result should match the method:

```
function arrayEvenItemIncrement(myArray){
    for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if (myArray[i]%2==0){
            myArray[i]++;
        }
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

I tried using `for (i of myArray){ }` but this still doesn't serve my purpose.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)?

Comment: myArray.map(a => a%2 ? a : a++);

Comment: Can you show the example python code you would have used?

Comment: Just write `for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) if (myArray[i]%2==0) myArray[i]++;` on one line if you feel a need for it. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the clearest way to do what you want here would be to map to a new array instead of mutating the old one:

```
const arrayEvenItemIncrement = myArray =>
  myArray.map((val, i) => i % 2 === 1 ? val : val + 1);
```

If you *have* to mutate the existing array, it gets significantly uglier.

```
const arrayEvenItemIncrement = myArray => (
  myArray.forEach((val, i) => { if (i % 2 === 0) myArray[i]++; }), myArray);
```

or

```
const arrayEvenItemIncrement = myArray => {
  myArray.forEach((val, i) => { if (i % 2 === 0) myArray[i]++; }); return myArray };
```

But I wouldn't recommend that - put it on multiple lines instead.

You can technically squeeze any JS code into a single line, but past simple manipulations, it usually isn't a good idea because it sacrifices readability, which is far more important than reducing LoC. Professional, maintainable code is not a golfing competition.

Comment: I am going with the forEach approach.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answers.
I have settled for this:

`myArray.forEach(el=>el%2===0?newArray.push(el):null);`